# I'm trying to hover an element and underline another in CSS - SquareSpace

Tags: css, hover, squarespace, underline

I'm making a squarespace website and I'm trying to trigger and underline from one element by hovering over another with CSS. I have targeted and found the two elements but it's not working.

I've tried everything and found both selectors but it still doesn't work.

This is the first selector to hover over:

```
#block-3b9da8935751df7fd9e0.sqs-block-image .design-layout-poster .image-overlay
```

and I want this to under line:

```
#block-3b9da8935751df7fd9e0 p.min-font-set
```

This is the Custom CSS I've tried to get it to work:

```
#block-3b9da8935751df7fd9e0 p.min-font-set
{
    text-decoration: none;
} 

#block-3b9da8935751df7fd9e0.sqs-block-image .design-layout-poster .image-overlay:hover #block-3b9da8935751df7fd9e0 p.min-font-set 
{
     text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Individually they change the styling but when I put it all together it doesn't do anything. If anyone has any insight into this. Please let me know!

Comment: I've not used SquareSpace, but I'm guessing you should use JavaScript.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the site/page in question? If so, consider editing your question to do so. You can use a yoursite.squarespace.com/your-page URL, and provide the view-only password if necessary. That usually makes it easier to answer Squarespace-specific, CSS-related questions of this sort.